# Cant delete Polygon after using the create polygon tool

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing

I used the "create Polygon tool" with no active layer in edit mode. I now can't delete this polygon. I turn off all layers and it is still on screen. I can't select it or delete it. I have tried restarting the program but it remains. Is there an invisible 'scratch' layer I need to empty? QGIS V3.22

Answer (score 3):

Fixed....If this happens to you then you have most likely used the anotation create polygon tool. So use the Modify Annotations button (white arrow) >select the annotation you created (in this case a polygon) then press delete. GONE!